# null pointer error at textfield even though value is entered

Tags: java

I keep getting a null exception error and I cant seem to fix it. I know a null pointer error is usually raised when your trying to use a value that is null but I pass a value to the textfield so Im confused. Looking for feedback:

exact error code: (this is where I add the actionlistner to button bt28)

> "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at GUI$4.actionPerformed(GUI.java:231) ...etc"

P.s. this class is called in a main class which is why that's not here. I've imported awt, swing and util.

```
public class GUI{
CardLayout cl=new CardLayout();
private String cardNum, pin; 

JLabel header1,header2,header3,header4;

JButton bt01= new JButton("");
//bt01.setBounds(100,150,100,40);
JButton bt02= new JButton("");
JButton bt03= new JButton("");
JButton bt04= new JButton("");
JButton bt05= new JButton("");
JButton bt06= new JButton("");
JButton bt07= new JButton("");
JButton bt08= new JButton("Continue");

JButton bt21= new JButton("");
JButton bt22= new JButton("");
JButton bt23= new JButton("");
JButton bt24= new JButton("");
JButton bt25= new JButton("");
JButton bt26= new JButton("");
JButton bt27= new JButton("");
JButton bt28= new JButton("Continue");

JButton bt31= new JButton("");
JButton bt32= new JButton("");
JButton bt33= new JButton("");
JButton bt34= new JButton("");
JButton bt35= new JButton("Balance Query");
JButton bt36= new JButton("Withdraw");
JButton bt37= new JButton("Deposit");
JButton bt38= new JButton("");

JButton bt41= new JButton("A");
JButton bt42= new JButton("B");
JButton bt43= new JButton("C");
JButton bt44= new JButton("D");
JButton bt45= new JButton("E");
JButton bt46= new JButton("");
JButton bt47= new JButton("Business Accounts");
JButton bt48= new JButton("Cancel");

JPanel panelCont=new JPanel();
JPanel GUI1= new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JPanel GUI2= new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JPanel GUI3= new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JPanel GUI4= new JPanel(new BorderLayout());



public GUI(){

    JFrame frame1 = new JFrame ("JLCB Automated Banking Machine v 1.0 ");
    frame1.setPreferredSize (new Dimension(500, 200));
    header1= new JLabel("JLCB Automated Banking Machine");

    JPanel nPanel1= new JPanel();
    nPanel1.add(header1);
    GUI1.add(nPanel1,BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JLabel cardnumLabel =new JLabel("Enter Card Number");
    JTextField txt= new JTextField(15);

    txt.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent cl){
            cardNum=txt.getText();
            txt.setText(null);
        }
    });

    JPanel cPanel1= new JPanel();
    cPanel1.add(cardnumLabel);
    cPanel1.add(txt);
    GUI1.add(cPanel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel wPanel1=new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,0));
    wPanel1.add(bt01);
    wPanel1.add(bt02);
    wPanel1.add(bt03);
    wPanel1.add(bt04);

    JPanel ePanel1=new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,0));
    ePanel1.add(bt05);
    ePanel1.add(bt06);
    ePanel1.add(bt07);
    ePanel1.add(bt08);

    GUI1.add(wPanel1,BorderLayout.WEST);
    GUI1.add(ePanel1,BorderLayout.EAST);

    //................................
    //                               .
    //           GUI2                .
    //................................ 
    JFrame frame2 = new JFrame ("JLCB Automated Banking Machine v 1.0 ");
    frame2.setPreferredSize (new Dimension(500, 200));
    header2= new JLabel("JLCB Automated Banking Machine");


    JPanel nPanel2= new JPanel();
    nPanel2.add(header1);
    GUI2.add(nPanel2,BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JLabel pinLabel =new JLabel("Enter your pin");
    JTextField txt2= new JTextField(15);

    txt2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent cl){
            pin=txt2.getText();
            txt2.setText(null);
        }
    });

    JPanel cPanel2= new JPanel();
    cPanel2.add(pinLabel);
    cPanel2.add(txt2);
    GUI2.add(cPanel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel wPanel2=new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,0));
    wPanel2.add(bt21);
    wPanel2.add(bt22);
    wPanel2.add(bt23);
    wPanel2.add(bt24);

    JPanel ePanel2=new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,0));
    ePanel2.add(bt25);
    ePanel2.add(bt26);
    ePanel2.add(bt27);
    ePanel2.add(bt28);

    GUI2.add(wPanel2,BorderLayout.WEST);
    GUI2.add(ePanel2,BorderLayout.EAST);
    //................................
    //                               .
    //           GUI3                .
    //................................

    JFrame frame3 = new JFrame ("JLCB Automated Banking Machine v 1.0 ");
    frame3.setPreferredSize (new Dimension(500, 200));
    header3= new JLabel("JLCB Automated Banking Machine");

    JPanel nPanel3= new JPanel();
    nPanel3.add(header1);
    GUI3.add(nPanel3,BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JLabel txt3 =new JLabel("Please select from the buttons on the right");

    JPanel cPanel3= new JPanel();
    cPanel3.add(txt3);
    GUI3.add(cPanel3, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel wPanel3=new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,0));
    wPanel3.add(bt31);
    wPanel3.add(bt32);
    wPanel3.add(bt33);
    wPanel3.add(bt34);

    JPanel ePanel3=new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,0));
    ePanel3.add(bt35);
    ePanel3.add(bt36);
    ePanel3.add(bt37);
    ePanel3.add(bt38);

    GUI3.add(wPanel3,BorderLayout.WEST);
    GUI3.add(ePanel3,BorderLayout.EAST);
    //..................................
    //                                 .
    //           GUI4                  .
    //..................................

    JFrame frame4 = new JFrame ("JLCB Automated Banking Machine v 1.0 ");
    frame4.setPreferredSize (new Dimension(500, 200));
    header4= new JLabel("JLCB Automated Banking Machine");

    JPanel nPanel4= new JPanel();
    nPanel4.add(header4);
    GUI4.add(nPanel4,BorderLayout.NORTH);


    JPanel cPanel4= new JPanel();
    GUI4.add(cPanel4, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel wPanel4=new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,0));
    wPanel4.add(bt41);
    wPanel4.add(bt42);
    wPanel4.add(bt43);
    wPanel4.add(bt44);

    JPanel ePanel4=new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,0));
    ePanel4.add(bt45);
    ePanel4.add(bt46);
    ePanel4.add(bt47);
    ePanel4.add(bt48);

    GUI4.add(wPanel4,BorderLayout.WEST);
    GUI4.add(ePanel4,BorderLayout.EAST);

    //---------------------------------------------------

    panelCont.setLayout(cl);

    panelCont.add(GUI1, "1");
    panelCont.add(GUI2, "2");
    panelCont.add(GUI3, "3");
    cl.show(panelCont,"1");


    String a ="100001 1111 15984789.74";


        bt08.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            cl.show(panelCont,"2");
        }
    }); 

        bt28.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent r){
            if (cardNum.equals(a.substring(0, a.indexOf(" "))) &&  pin.equals(a.substring(a.indexOf(" ")+1,a.lastIndexOf(" ")))){
                cl.show(panelCont,"3");
                String acc="a";
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid accoun number or pin");
                cl.show(panelCont,"3");

            }

        }
    });

           bt35.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            cl.show(panelCont,"3"); 
          }         
    });

        bt36.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            cl.show(panelCont,"3");   

        }
    });

        bt37.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            cl.show(panelCont,"3");   

        }
    });

    frame1.add(panelCont);
    //(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame1.pack();
    frame1.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Comment: What's the value of the `cardNum` and `pin` variables when the bt28 ActionListener is called?

Comment: Those button variables, holy moly. You should research on `Collections` like `List`s.

Comment: cardNum and pin values should be whatever the user enters. I've been entering 100001 and 1111 to test it.

Comment: "*cardNum and pin values should be whatever the user enters*" where are those values set? What action/event it should react on, and what action/even actually "happens"?

Comment: after I create the text field [ JTextField txt2= new JTextField(15) ]    I added the action listener then set the text inside of it:     [ txt2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent cl){
            pin=txt2.getText();]

Comment: As you see you are adding listener for `txt2`. But what do you do when you actually write account number or pin? Are you interacting after that with `txt2`? Probably not, you are using other element ("continue" button) but that listener has nothing to do with it...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your values for cardNum and pin are never assigned in the actionListeners for txt and txt2. You should pull the values in the event that the user clicks the continue button. See my code below.

```
        bt28.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent r) {

            cardNum = txt.getText();
            pin = txt2.getText();

            if (cardNum.equals(a.substring(0, a.indexOf(" "))) && pin.equals(a.substring(a.indexOf(" ") + 1, a.lastIndexOf(" ")))) {
                cl.show(panelCont, "3");
                String acc = "a";
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid accoun number or pin");
                cl.show(panelCont, "3");

            }

        }
    });
```